# Customize Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have some different PDF documents (buy not the TeX files) that I want to collect into a single PDF file with a matching ToC.

I want to create a separate file containing only the ToC for the compendium and I would like it to look like this:

```
                                Table of Contents

Introduction .................................................................. 1
Basic Exercises ............................................................... 2
The Building Blocks of an Atom ................................................ 5
Background Radiation .......................................................... 9
```

and so forth.

So, I want to add every single line of the ToC by hand and also the page numbers.

How do I do that?

P.S. The ToC has to be in Danish, if that is of any importance.

Comment: Are you looking for the `\addcontentsline` command?

Comment: @Teepeemm Maybe. `:-)` Can you show a complete working example? If so, I can tell you if that is what I'm looking for. `:-)`

Comment: The `pdfpages` package defines an `\includepdf` command, and an experimental`addtotoc`  option. Maybe it could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-use the normal toc machinery as noted in comments but you don't really need a two pass mechanism and `.toc` file as you know all the page numbers in advance.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Table of Contents}\date{}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

 \maketitle


Introduction \dotfill\  1

Basic Exercises \dotfill\  2

The Building Blocks of an Atom \dotfill\  5

Background Radiation \dotfill\  9

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David! That is a nice and easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I created some dummy documents using [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum):

- `introduction.pdf`: `\section{Introduction}\lipsum[1-10]`
- `basic_exercises.pdf`: `\section{Basic Exercises}\lipsum[1-20]`
- `buiding_blocks_of_an_atom.pdf`: `\section{Building Blocks of an Atom}\lipsum[1-30]`
- `background_radiation.pdf`: `\section{Background Radiation}\lipsum[1-40]`

These were included in a main document in the following way via [`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), automating the creation of a ToC:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newsection}{o m}{%
  \clearpage
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname% If you're using hyperref
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\includepdf[pages=-]{#1}}%
    {\includepdf[pages=-]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newsection[introduction]{Introduction}% introduction.pdf

\newsection[basic_exercises]{Basic Exercises}% basic_exercises.pdf

\newsection[building_blocks_of_an_atom]{The Building Blocks of an Atom}% building_blocks_of_an_atom.pdf

\newsection[background_radiation]{Background Radiation}% background_radiation.pdf

\end{document}
```

One could customize this further with `pdfpages`' `addtotoc` key-value. [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) wasn't needed, but you may be using it.

Comment: Thanks alot, Werner! The slight problem with this approach is, that when I include PDF filer using `pdfpages`, some of the pages doesn't get included into the new document for some reason. Also, I have subsections in the ToC.